# How to get list of all latest EIP of AWS for all regions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, eip

I would like to know how can I list out all the EIP or public IP of aws for all regions?

Maybe via aws cli or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have waited but nobody answered, hence after waiting for 2 mins now I am going to answer my own question.

Check the below python code, it will list out number of EIP in each region aws have

```
import requests, ipaddress, boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
awsRegions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

resp = requests.get('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json')

for eachRegion in awsRegions:
      ip_pool = []
      for prefix in resp.json()['prefixes']:
            if prefix['region'] == eachRegion and prefix['service'] == 'EC2':
                  ip_pool.append(prefix['ip_prefix'])
      total_ip = []
      for eachCIDR in ip_pool:
            net = ipaddress.ip_network(eachCIDR)
            total_ip.append(int(net.num_addresses))

      print (f'[{eachRegion}] total IP ==> {sum(total_ip)}')

exit()
```

Thanks for all the votes in advance.